# Not receiving correct output for the following nested for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I need an explanation for the following loop:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 30;

for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++) {
    for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
        x = x + 6; 
        y = y - 2; 
        if (x == 6) {
            break;
        }
        x = x + 3;
    }
    y = y - 2;
}

System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

The way I'm seeing it is that the 'outer' loop is running 3 times and the 'inner' loop is running 9 times. When I go through the 'inner' loop, `x` becomes 6, and we break out of the 'inner' loop after we get the value for `y`, which is 28. So now, the value of `x` is 6, and now I go through the 'outer' loop which runs 3 times, so 3 times 2 is equal to 6, so I subtract that from 28, and I end up with 22.

Output:

```
6 22
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I know the output should be `60 10`, but I am not getting this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Execute it by hand. Write down the values of x and y after every single statement.  I assume this is some sort of puzzle, rather than code expected to be useful for anything.

Comment: You code outpu result is 60 10

Comment: @TongChen - same here,60 10

Comment: @LêHoàngDững - the second time through the outer loop, we enter the inner loop and set x = 12, so the break no longer executes.  Thus the inner loop loops 3 times and we add 27 to x.  6 + 27 + 27 = 60

Comment: My result is `60 10`

Comment: @user13784117 Thank you for your response, and I've really been trying to follow along this for the past minutes, but I'm not getting how the whole process is working. I'm trying to do things by hand as well, running the inner loop 3 times. The first loop, we end up with 6, the second loop, we end up with 15, and the third loop, we end up with 24, which isn't even close to 60. I'm not fully understanding your process. If you could suggest what's wrong with what I just stated, that would be great.

Comment: When `outer` is first incremented (to 1), the value of `x` is 6. On the next increment, it has increased by 27 and is 33. On the next increment, it has increased by 27 and is 60. On the next increment, `outer == 3` and the loop is over. In total, the inner loop will execute 1 + 3 + 3 = 7 times.

Comment: @AndrewF how are you getting 27?

Comment: There are two loops. The entirety of the inner loop, in its completion, will either increase x by 6 (if `x == 0`)  or will increase x by 27 (+ 6 + 3 + 6 + 3 + 6 + 3). You may need to research the meaning of the `break;` statement.

Comment: @AndrewF thanks for the response. I finally ended up getting 60 as the result for x, but now I'm not receiving 10 for y. For y, I'm getting 18 + 2 = 20 in the inner loop and the outer loop I'm getting 3 * 2 = 6, so 20 + 6 = 26. Subtracting this from 30 I'm getting 4 as the result for y.

Comment: Same logic applies. First execution of outer loop reduces y by 2+2=4, second and third reduce y by 3x2+2=8.  30-(4+8+8)=10.

Comment: Finally understand it, thank you so much; I obtained the correct output. It's really just a matter of understanding the for loops, the operations inside aren't really much to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

I have copied and pasted your code in my pc and I get the out put
60 10
I think your are running a different file in your IDE.
What IDE do you use?

Comment: The issue is not with the code, the issue here is understanding the code ("I need an explanation") and reproducing its flow mentally.